# Faraday rails started with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to show data from this website: https://baconipsum.com/json-api/ , but I don't know where to write the code of it in my app.  What code do I have to write for controllers and in views?

Comment: Where to place HTTP calls in your Rails app is a matter of opinion. But my opinion is that you should not shoehorn it into either the model, view or controller. They all already have responsibilities. Instead create a separate client object which is responsible for touching the application boundry and normalizing the response to models which your application deals with. This gives you a class that can be tested in isolation and isolates your application so that changes to the collaborator (the api) doesn't break huge chunks of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup faraday:

```rb
bacon = Faraday.new("https://baconipsum.com/") do |f|
  f.response :json # automatically parse responses as json
end
```

Send a request in the controller:

```rb
@bacon = bacon.get("api/", type: 'all-meat', sentences: 1).body # => ["Leberkas frankfurter chicken tongue."]
```

Use it in the view:

```html
<% @bacon.each do |meat| %>
  <p> 
    <%= meat %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

*https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/*

**Update**

There are many ways to set it up. Very simple set up could look like this:

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

    # NOTE: this method will be accessible in any controller
    #       that inherits from ApplicationController
    def baconipsum
      # NOTE: memoize for a bit of performance, in case you're
      #       making multiple calls to this method.
      @baconipsum ||= Faraday.new("https://baconipsum.com/") do |f|
        f.response :json
      end
    end
end

# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    # I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with it;
    # change this to fit your use case.
    @bacon = baconipsum.get("api/", type: 'all-meat').body
  end
end

# app/views/articles/show.html.erb
<% @bacon.each do |meat| %>
  <p> <%= meat %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: where I have to write the code for Setup Faraday and where to write the code for requesting the controller

Comment: @DebannitaPal to start nice and simple, just put all of it together in the controller action. you can update your question with a few more details and maybe some code that you have, so I can understand where you're stuck.

Comment: Kindly help me. I have added all the codes on github

Comment: see the update. hope it helps.

Comment: segmentation fault doesn't seem related to this. in ruby it's often a temporary fault. try restarting the rails server. if it persist, sounds like it should be a whole other question.

Comment: Initially, when i open localhost it is working but when i click to show the article, server stopped to works

Comment: where I have to writte these:   require 'faraday'
require 'faraday/net_http'
Faraday.default_adapter = :net_http

Comment: try bumping your ruby version to `2.7.6`, it should fix segfault. you don't need to `require` anything. `:net_http` is already the default.

Comment: Hey, thank you this works for me. Can you please understand me these codes of Application Controller and @bacon = baconipsum.get("api/", type: 'all-meat').body this line

Comment: Help me with this please,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73098279/rails-bootstrap-modal-is-not-showing